# Should I stop redirecting after successful POST or PUT requests?

Tags: http

It seems common in the Rails community, at least, to respond to successful `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` requests by redirecting instead of returning success. For instance, if I `PUT` a legal change to my user profile, the idiomatic response would be a `302 Redirect` to the profile page.

Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't we be returning `200 OK` from the request? Or a `201 Created`, in the case of a `POST` request? Either of those, in the [HTTP/1.1 Status Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) are allowed to (or required to) include a response, anyway.

I guess I'm wondering, before I go and "fix" my application, whether there is there a *darn* good reason why the community has gone the way of redirects instead of successful responses.

Comment: Hmm, having read some (very nice) answers which point me to the POST-Redirect-GET pattern, I'm also curious how people feel about 303 responses?

Comment: 302 is vastly more common in practice than 303. They have the same effect in modern web browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume, your use of the `PUT` verb notwithstanding, that you're talking about a web app that will be accessed primarily through the browser. In that case, the usual reason for following up a POST with a redirect is the [post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which avoids duplicate requests caused by a user refreshing or using the back and forward controls of their browser. It seems that in many instances this pattern is overloaded by redirecting not to a success page, but to the next most likely place the user would visit. I don't think either way you mention is necessarily wrong, but doing the redirect may be more user-friendly at the expense of not strictly adhering to the semantics of HTTP.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I mean an app accessed through the browser.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [POST-Redirect-GET (PRG) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This pattern will prevent clients from (accidently) re-executing non-idempotent requests when for example navigating forth and back in browser's history.

It's a good general web development practice which doesn't only apply on RoR. I'd just keep it as is.

Comment: I know it's not really RoR-specific; I figured that would attract a larger audience. I have retagged.

Comment: I however added a broader tag.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, yes, probably. However HTTP clients and servers are a mess when it comes to standardization and don't always agree on proper protocol. Redirecting after a post helps avoid things like duplicate form submissions.